# Formatting Output in Java from ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to format my output of Marks from 2 different `ArrayList`s. One for `Homework`, another for `Exams`. The format I'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

My Code so far is

```
public void example() {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Subject: "+subjectString);
      System.out.print("Homework Mark: ");
      for(int i = 0; i <= arrayList1.size()-1; i++){
          System.out.printf("",arrayList1.get(i));
       }
    }
}
```

But I cannot get it to work in any way.

Comment: Why do you print "Homework Mark:" before "Assignment"?

Comment: You say it doesn't work. What does it do? Give the wrong output? What wrong output? Give an error message? What error message?

Comment: Don't look through lists like that. ```For one, for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)``` is more idiomatic and makes boundaries more elegant.  But don't do that, do ```for (Object o : arrayList1)```. If that array list happens to be a linked list, it'll still be fast.

Comment: Look at how you're using ```printf()```.  The first parameter is a format string, and there's no format in it.

Comment: It is not appropriate to vandalize the question in any case, and especially so if it has received answers.

Comment: I'm not sure why the original code above was altered, but I do not believe that that is the right place to do that, as it can lead to answers that no longer appear to match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
public void load() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Subject: "+subjectString);
    System.out.print("Homework Mark: \t");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(arrayList1.get(i) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Exam Mark: \t");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList2.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(arrayList2.get(i) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

using `\t` will add tabs to organize the output format

Comment: You are still missing the "Assignment" row.

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan So was the OP for that matter, though it would be trivial to add and TBH, I missed that too in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `\t` character will insert tabs. You can use this to align columns appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of problems I see right away are:

1) Using `System.out.printf` without an empty string for the format, meaning only an empty string will be printed.

2) It seems you desired your output to aligned into columns, which you can't do with just `System.out.print`, but `System.out.printf` allows you to do so (and without relying on tabs) by specific width spacing.

Also note the `-` minus sign in the format when printing the row titles, which causes them to left align with the specified spacing and matching  your desired output.

Below is an adjusted version of your code:

```
public static void load() {
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Subject: "+subjectString);
   System.out.printf("%-19s", "Homework Mark: ");

   for (int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++) {
      System.out.printf("%7d", arrayList1.get(i));
   }

   System.out.println("");
   System.out.printf("%-19s", "Exam Mark: ");

   for (int i = 0; i < arrayList2.size(); i++) {
      System.out.printf("%7d", arrayList2.get(i));
   }

   System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Note, the original code in the original post appears to have been altered (shortened) for some reason. The code above is based on what was originally posted.

Comment: it was empty because everything i entered resulted in failure :3 thanks for your help